# How do I use find to search but exclude certain directories?

Tags: find

How can I advice `find` not to descend in specific (multiple) directories? I would like to invoke `find` directly, so no features of `bash` can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `find . -name "file.tofind" ! -path "dir/to/exclude/*"`?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Exactly! Cheers

Comment: Well, no, sorry. Doesn't work as expected. `find /proc -name net ! -path /proc/sys` will iterate through `/proc/sys` and return `/proc/sys/net` which is exactly what I don't want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my bad: try ! -path "/proc/sys/*"

Comment: Hm :-/ It's still not working as expected. Is the asterisk `*` in "/proc/sys/*" expanded by the shell or is it recognized by `find`?

Comment: Now it works perfectly: If **multiple** directories need to be excluded multiple expressions such as `! -path "/proc/*"` need to be added. (And in my case I included all exclusion-expressions in round brackets.)